# How to get name of the properties which are null in the list along with a fixed property which should be always there in the list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to get a list which contains the name of the properties which have value equals to null along with a property(InvoiceNumber) which should be always there .

```
public class InvoiceDetails
{
     public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
     public string InvoiceClass { get; set; }
     public string ExpenseMethod { get; set; }
     public string FromDate { get; set; }
     public string ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have two set of code, (#1) -This only returns InvoiceNumber where other properties values mentioned in code are equal to null , this is the property which should be always there in the list. This (#2) returns the properties having value equal to null.But I want to somehow return list having InvoiceNumber along with the property name which were null.

```
(#1) var invoice= InvoiceDetails.Where(x => x.FromDate == null || x.ExpenseMethod == null || x.ToDate == null).Select(s => s.InvoiceNumber ).Distinct().ToList();

(#2) var result = typeof(InvoiceDetails).GetProperties()
        .Select(x => new { property = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(objInvoiceDetails) })
        .Where(x => x.value != null)
        .ToList();
```

E.g 101| FromDate |ExpenseMethod |
Here for invoice number 101 property FromDate and Expense method had null values

Comment: Distinct only works with a class that has IEquatable<T> Interface.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0  Adding the interface should eliminate the Where and just use Distinct().  You have to make sure the interface handles the null conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
I'm trying to get a list which contains the name of the properties which have value equals to null along with a property(InvoiceNumber)
```

Sounds like you want to return a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var nullInvoices = InvoiceDetails.
    Where(x => x.FromDate == null || x.ExpenseMethod == null || x.ToDate == null).
    Distinct();
foreach (var invoiceDetails in nullInvoices )
{
    var key = invoiceDetails.InvoiceNumber;
    var val = typeof(InvoiceDetails).GetProperties().
        Where(x => x.GetValue(invoiceDetails) == null).
        Select(x => x.Name).
        ToList();
    dictionary[key] = val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,the solution which you have given is good , but it needs to be modified a bit .You have declared a Dictionary which holds value of type  list<string> , but the value assigned to val variable inside foreach is List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>.You need to change it to Where(x => x.GetValue(invoiceDetails ) == null).Select(x=>x.Name)

Comment: good, point. updated.